# Error MSB4044: The "AdjustJavacVersionArguments" task was not given a value for the required parameter "JdkVersion"

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to run an android application throw Visual Studio (7.4 Build 1033)
and it seems that I'm having this problem :

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2):
>   Error MSB4044: The "AdjustJavacVersionArguments" task was not given a
>   value for the required parameter "JdkVersion". (MSB4044)

And... I don't know how to solve this issue...

I saw that Visual Studio has the correct path to JDK (mentionned "Found" in the UI) and also the version of JDK is 1.8.

Any hints for helping me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem.
Visual Studio was using the JDK from Android Studio...
So I changed the path and begin to use the JDK that I installed with oracle (For instance (Mac) : `../Library/Java/...`

Comment: Thanks!  We had the same problem here and this worked perfectly.  We just downloaded the JDK 8 from Oracle, and then used that path.  Need to select all the way down to "Home"

Comment: Having the same problem. I have two versions of JDK. 8 and 10. With 8 it works fine but not with 10. Thoughts?

Comment: @bluepiranha in visual studio, did you change the path in order to use java 8 JDK ?

Comment: @Damiii What's the exact step and selection. Can you elaborate please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To check the issue:

1. Go to Visual studio `Preferences >> SDK Location >> Android`
2. Select the Locations tab

Here you will see the Location targeted for each, we are facing issue with JDK.

3. Click on the folder selector so to navigate to the current location been pointed.
4. In my case it was pointing to `"usr/"`  folder
5. Check the `"libexec"` folder inside `"usr/"` folder and look for `"Java_Home"`
6. Execute the file `"Java_Home"`, it will give you the location it is pointing toin the terminal window.

In my case it was pointing to `"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.jdk/Contents/Home"`

Now we know the location our VS is pointing to and we need to change this to required one. in my case `"JDk 1.8"`

7. Click on the folder selector again and navigate to the folder `"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines"`
8. Here navigate to the desired JDK till `"Contents/Home"`.

Make sure once you select and come back to VS the green tick is all set.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurred on my machine after someone/something unexpectedly replaced JDK version 1.8 LTE with JDK 11 LTE. Seems that Xamarin is not compatible with any Java version except version 1.8.

[Link to Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/jdk9-errors)

Note that the version warning described in that article does not occur. Instead you run into the "AdjustJavacVersionArguments" error described above.

Having both versions installed in parallel seems to work fine, after I manually re-installed 1.8 and set the correct path to the JDK in Visual Studio (Tools-Options-Xamarin-Android Settings-Java Develoipment Kit Location") the error went away and I could successfully build and deploy my Xamarin projects again.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall [JDK 1.8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). [MS Instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/update-jdk?tabs=windows)

[image]

Visual Studio was pointed to JDK 1.8 but for some reason it was no good.

[image]

**WARNING** - make sure to fix the path to your jdk in visual studio. For me what I installed was a different version of 1.8 than the one I had previously. If Visual studio is still using the old jdk path it won't work. This should be obvious but for me it wasn't.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192 <-- old path. visual studio still thought this was good. good, that is, until build time.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201 <-- new path. from the install of JDK 1.8 that I did today. Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings > Java Development Kit Location needs to be pointing to this.
```